# Nltk and Tagging Idioms

Tags: nltk

I'm studying Spanish and have started out with two corpa:

cess_esp and conll2002/esp

I notice that if I do the following for the `cess_esp` corpus:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import cess_esp as cess
>>> symbols = list(set(w[0].lower() for s in cess.tagged_sents() for w in s))
>>> list(filter(lambda x: "cabo" in x, symbols))
['llevaron_a_cabo', 'llevaran_a_cabo', 'cabo', 'llevó_a_cabo', 'llevado_a_cabo', 'llevarán_a_cabo', 'lleva_a_cabo', 'al_cabo_de', 'llevan_a_cabo', 'al_cabo', 'llevadas_a_cabo', 'llevará_a_cabo', 'llevarse_a_cabo', 'llevar_a_cabo', 'al_fin_y_al_cabo']
```

That it seems to represent idioms with an underscore between words. Does nltk have functionality to deal with these underscores when training a tagger?

Here is my pos tagger. How do I update it so that I can tag idioms?

```
from nltk.corpus import cess_esp as cess
spanish_sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/spanish.pickle')

def trigram_tagger(training_set):
   default_tagger = nltk.DefaultTagger('NN')
   unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(training_set, backoff=default_tagger)
   bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(training_set, backoff=unigram_tagger)
   return nltk.TrigramTagger(training_set, backoff=bigram_tagger)

def tag_sentences(tagger, sentence_tokenizer, sentences):
   tokenized_sentences = sentence_tokenizer.tokenize(sentences)
   return [tagger.tag(word_tokenize(s)) for s in tokenized_sentences]

tagger = trigram_tagger(cess.tagged_sents())
print(tag_sentences(tagger, spanish_sentence_tokenizer, sentences))
```

Comment: They were tokenised as a single token in your corpus so you should treat them as other tokens and assign a single POS, no need to "un-tokenise" them.